# IF ELSE statement with && and || condition

Tags: javascript, if-statement, checkbox

I have a group of checkboxes (id = "first" id = "second") and the main checkbox (id = "main").

```
<input type='checkbox' id="main_button" onclick="Indeterminate()"><label for="main_button">Main checkbox of group</label> 
<input type='checkbox' id="first" onclick="Indeterminate()"><label for="first">First thing</label>
<input type='checkbox' id="second" onclick="Indeterminate()"><label for="second">Second thing</label>
```

If one or more of the group checkbox checked then the main have indeterminate condition. If all checked then the main checkbox have also checked condition.

```
function Indeterminate() {
    if (document.getElementById('first').checked || document.getElementById('second').checked) {
        document.getElementById('main_button').indeterminate = true;
    } else if (document.getElementById('first').checked && document.getElementById('second').checked) {
        document.getElementById('main_button').checked;
    } else { 
        document.getElementById('main_button').indeterminate = false; 
    }    
}
```

In my IF ELSE statement, conditions IF and ELSE works, but there is something wrong with ELSE IF. Probably doing a simple mistake or? Thank you!

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/davorp7/s3Lwp5so/3/)

Comment: First should be `&&` then `||`

Comment: What should happen if the _main_button_ is checked / unchecked  directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your && code is right, but it's the && situation is apart of you || code, so When || is not true, the && will not true too. Just change their sequence.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var main = document.getElementById('main_button');
var first = document.getElementById('first');
var second = document.getElementById('second');

function Indeterminate() {
  if (first.checked && second.checked) {
    main.checked = true;
    main.indeterminate = false;
  } else if (first.checked || second.checked)
    main.indeterminate = true;
  else
    main.indeterminate = false;

}
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' id="main_button" onclick="Indeterminate()">
<label for="main_button">Main checkbox of group</label>
<input type='checkbox' id="first" onclick="Indeterminate()">
<label for="first">First thing</label>
<input type='checkbox' id="second" onclick="Indeterminate()">
<label for="second">Second thing</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

As commented before, you should move `&&` before `||`.

Reason for this is if first is selected or both is selected, `first.checked || second.checked` will always be true. Only situation when `||` will fail is when both are unchecked, and then `&&` will also fail.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/s3Lwp5so/7/)

Updated Code

```js
function Indeterminate() {
  var first = document.getElementById('first').checked;
  var second = document.getElementById('second').checked
  var main = document.getElementById('main_button');
  if (first && second) {
    main.indeterminate = false;
    main.checked = true
  } else {
    main.checked = main.indeterminate = first || second
  }
}
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' id="main_button" onclick="Indeterminate()">
<label for="main_button">Main checkbox of group</label>
<br>
<input type='checkbox' id="first" onclick="Indeterminate()">
<label for="first">First thing</label>
<br>
<input type='checkbox' id="second" onclick="Indeterminate()">
<label for="second">Second thing</label>
```

As commented by [Bekim Bacaj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5896426/bekim-bacaj), I have updated my code. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/s3Lwp5so/8/)

Comment: what is the purpose of Main checkbox existence if it does nothing?! :)

Comment: @BekimBacaj I just rectified OP code. He might have another handler to select all but that is outside scope of this question

Comment: I've asked him the same question, as I'm pretty sure he hasn't thought of it yet. The problem is that the approach is extremely limiting

Comment: @BekimBacaj I have added an updated fiddle. Hope that clarifies

Comment: This is just a small example of code that I will be incorporated into the existing master code. I have a map in SVG and using checkboxes displaying its layers. I have couple groups of layers, and so far I have not incorporated indeterminate function for main checkboxes of the groups. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are getting the meaning of `||` wrong. It means `or` in the sense that either the left or the right expression is true - **or both**!

Therefore, your `else if` will never be called, because if `a.checked && b.checked` is true, then `a.checked || b.checked` will always be true as well, and the `if` will be executed before the `else if` is even checked.

Therefore, the correct solution is:

```
function Indeterminate() {
    if (document.getElementById('first').checked && document.getElementById('second').checked) {
        document.getElementById('main_button').checked;
    } else if (document.getElementById('first').checked || document.getElementById('second').checked) {
        document.getElementById('main_button').indeterminate = true;
    } else { 
        document.getElementById('main_button').indeterminate = false; 
    }    
}
```

Here, you first check for the more specific condition `a.checked && b.checked`. Only if that condition is not true, the weaker condition `a.checked || b.checked` is evaluated.